# Cant make the google API process a WAV Audio

Tags: google-api, speech-recognition, text-to-speech, wav, google-cloud-speech

I want to transcribe a simple audio from a phone call.

I'm currently working with the Speech API

```
const speech = require('@google-cloud/speech').v1p1beta1;
```

The Information about the Audio I'm trying to transcribe:

- Codec: PCM MU-LAW (mlaw)
- Channels: Stereo
- Sample Rate: 8000
- Bits per Sample: 16
- Duration: 35 seconds

I'm using this configuration for the API:

```
const requestGoogle = {
      audio: {
        uri: [ my audio location ]
      },
      config: {
        audioChannelCount: 2,
        enableSeparateRecognitionPerChannel: true,
        enableAutomaticPunctuation: true,
        languageCode,
        model: 'default',
        useEnhanced: true,
        interactionType: 'PHONE_CALL',
        encoding: 'MULAW',
        microphoneDistance: 'NEARFIELD',
        recordingDeviceType: 'PHONE_LINE',
      }
    };
```

When requesting that to the API I get a 400 response status with the error message:

> {
>
> "error": "3 INVALID_ARGUMENT: Invalid recognition 'config': bad channel count."
>
> }

If someone could help me with this would be awesome, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Convert the Codec data - from Codec: PCM MU-LAW (mlaw) - to - Codec: PCM - using G711 decoder.

Use the Channel : Mono.